# Is it possible to claim an existing YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

Someone has reserved a YouTube channel I would like to use myself, let's call it `youtube.com/mybusiness`.

The `youtube.com/mybusiness` channel doesn't seem to be used any longer and was never a highly regarded channel as its stats show:
- created in 2007
- 6 videos uploaded ever since
- 310 total views since then
- last video posted on June 2011 with 46 views

I have sent messages to the channel owner via the YouTube **Send Message** feature (one in June, 2012, and one in January, 2013) but never heard back from that person.

**Can/Will YouTube transfer the channel to myself?**

*PS: I have applied for the `mybusiness` trademark in the US and own that name on all the major social networking sites (Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn ...), could that help convincing YouTube?*

Answer (score 6):

No, unless the owner wants to do it there is no way that you could claim another username. just find another name, for example mybusinessofficial or anything else.

It may be helpful to read the [**YouTube's username trademark policy**](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151655).

Problem is, they're probably not infringing your trademark, as you may know, just using a name doesn't infringe a trademark, what is important is "how" they use it. that said, if they even try to upload any content, similar to yours, which imply that their channel is connected with your brand, then you may use [**YouTube Trademark Complaint Form**](https://support.google.com/youtube/bin/request.py?&contact_type=trademarkcomplaintb) to take down their content, their account or assign it to yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to `Omne` I may have found a way to get the username back. The [YouTube Username Policy](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151655) states the following:

> **Username Squatting**
>
> In general, **users are expected to be active** members within the YouTube
>   community. **If** an account is found to be overly **inactive**, **the account
>   may be reclaimed by YouTube without notice**. Inactivity may be
>   considered as:
>
> -**Not logging into the site for at least six months**.
>     -Never having uploaded video content
>     -**Not actively partaking in watching or commenting on videos or channels**
>
> In cases of username squatting,
>   YouTube may release usernames in cases of a valid trademark complaint.

I can't see whether the user has logged in or not within the last 6 months however the fact that he/she hasn't replied to a message I sent 7 months ago is a sign of hope. The other possibility is that the user isn't watching or commenting on videos (but I can't get any statistics about it).

I'm going to contact Youtube about this and see whether I can get that username.

Comment: Wishing you luck in getting your desired username back!